# SpringData MongoDB cannot determine IsNewStrategy during Auditing

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to enable Auditing using Annotations. My domain class has @Id field that is populated while constructing the object. I have added a java.util.Date field for lastModified and annotated it with @LastModifiedDate.

```java
@Document
public class Book {
    @Id
    private String name;
    private String isbn;
    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date lastModified;

    public Book(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

I have enabled auditing in the Spring Configuration XML using `<mongo:auditing/>.`

When I try to save an instance of my object, I get the following error:

```java
Book book1 = new Book("ABCD");
mongoOps.save(book1);
```

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported entity com.pankaj.Book! Could not determine IsNewStrategy.

I do not want to use the Auditable interface nor extend my domain classes from AbstractAuditable. I only want to use the Annotations.
Since I am not interested in the @CreatedBy and the @LastModifiedBy, I am not implementing the AuditAware interface as well.

I just want the @LastModifiedDate to work for my domain classes. What am I missing?

I am using version 1.7.0 of SpringData MongoDB.

Comment: problem seems to be  duplication of mappingContext. Look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40738105/spring-data-mongodb-mongoauditing-cause-illegalargumentexception-unsupporte/40764592#comment76784613_40764592

Answer (score 6):

You don't mention how you are configuring your MongoDB connection but if you are using AbstractMongoConfiguration, it will use the package of the actual configuration class to look for @Document annotated classes at startup.

If your entities are in a different package, you will have to manually hand that package by overriding AbstractMongoConfiguration.getMappingBasePackage(). Placing this in you Mongo Configuration class should do the trick (again, this is considering you are extending AbstractMongoConfiguration for your Mongo configuration):

```java
@Override
protected String getMappingBasePackage() {
    return "package.with.my.domain.classes";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue, later I determined that I was missing ID field with annotation;

```
@Id
private String Id
```

in my class I was trying to persist with

```
@Document(collection="collectionName")
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when using annotations only configuration.

When you put @EnableMongoAuditing on a configuration class, Spring will create a MappingContext bean.

Then you have to make sure the same mappingContext is being used in the MongoTemplate.

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoAuditing
@EnableMongoRepositories(value = "my.repositories.package", mongoTemplateRef = "myMongoTemplate")
class MongoConfig {

    @Autowired
    //Autowiring the MongoMappingContext will supply the same MongoMappingContext as the one used in auditing
    MongoMappingContext mongoMappingContext;

    @Bean
    MongoTemplate myMongoTemplate() {

        String databaseName = "mydbname";
        MongoDbFactory factory = new SimpleMongoDbFactory(mongoClient, databaseName);
        MongoConverter converter = new MappingMongoConverter(factory, mongoMappingContext);
        MongoTemplate mongoTemplate =  new MongoTemplate(factory, converter);
        return mongoTemplate;
    }
}
```

Comment: For anyone interested in accomplishing this via XML config: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40764592/177920

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and fixed it by extending the Document class with  AbstractPersistable. In you case it can be

```
public class Book extends AbstractAuditable
```

Answer (score 0):

My project running in version 1.6.2 runs normally, except that @ LastModifiedDate does not update. After I updated to version 1.7.1. I had the same problem as you.

I tried to implement the class: org. Springframework. Data. Domain. The Auditable this interface, seemingly can preserve the normal, but the createdBy and createdDate two fields could not be saved to the database.

Comment: Can you please edit your answer to be a bit clearer. Not sure what you are trying to say on the second paragraph.

Comment: Running my code against version 1.6.2 works for me. The `@LastModifiedDate` is updated, I guess it is detected that since the `@Id` is not null, this is an old object being modified. Perhaps there is a bug in 1.7.0.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am from China, my English is limited.I try to describe clearly.The meaning of the second paragraph is this: I try to do this: Book implements Auditable, no longer throw this exception: Unsupported entity. Com pankaj. Book!Could not determine IsNewStrategy.