# Spring Data MongoDB <mongo:auditing/> cause IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported entity Could not determine IsNewStrategy

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, maven

I upgrade my spring-data-mongodb (using maven) version to 1.9.5.RELEASE. (using MongoClient instead of Mongo).
My Session document class contains @LastModifiedDate annotation.

After the upgrade, i got java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported entity com...Session! Could not determine IsNewStrategy.

If i remove  from the configuration i don't get the error but it doesn't save the modifiedDate.
All the solutions I found related to MongoDB configuration using annotations and not xml file.
How can i solve this?

Maven dependencies:

```html
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
 <version>1.9.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
    <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Spring MongoDB configuration contain :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
 xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context classpath:org/springframework/context/factory/xml/spring-context-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo classpath:org/springframework/data/mongo/factory/xml/spring-mongo-1.8.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans classpath:org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/util classpath:org/springframework/util/factory/xml/spring-util-3.0.xsd">

 <bean class="com.....core.CascadingMongoEventListener"/>
 <bean class="com.....core.DataEventListener"/>
   
 <mongo:auditing/>
 
 <mongo:mongo-client id="mongo" host="${host}" port="${port}">
  <mongo:client-options connections-per-host="100"
                        connect-timeout="30000"
                        max-wait-time="15000"                                             
                        socket-keep-alive="true"
                        socket-timeout="60000" />  
 </mongo:mongo-client>
  
 <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
  <constructor-arg name="mongo" ref="mongo" />
  <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="${dbName}"/>  
  <property name="writeConcern">
            <util:constant static-field="com.mongodb.WriteConcern.SAFE" ></util:constant>
        </property>        
 </bean>
  
 <mongo:repositories base-package="com.....daos" mongo-template-ref="mongoTemplate">   
 </mongo:repositories>
 
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.....services"></context:component-scan>
 
 <!-- translate any MongoExceptions thrown in @Repository annotated classes -->
 <context:annotation-config /> 
</beans>
```

My Document:

```html
package com.....session;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.UUID;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.LastModifiedDate;

@Document(collection = "session")
public class Session {

 @Id
 protected UUID id;
 private DateTime creationDate;
 @LastModifiedDate
 private DateTime modifiedDate;

 public Session() {}
 
 //setters & getters 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to share a `MongoMappingContext` between auditing and the `MongoTemplate`.

First replace:

```
<mongo:auditing/>
```

with:

```
<bean id="mappingContext" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoMappingContext" />
<mongo:auditing mapping-context-ref="mappingContext"/>
```

Then add a `MongoDbFactory` and a `MongoConverter` to your xml settings as follows:

```
<mongo:db-factory id="mongoDbFactory" mongo-ref="mongo" dbname="${dbName}"/>
<mongo:mapping-converter id="mongoConverter" db-factory-ref="mongoDbFactory" mapping-context-ref="mappingContext"/>
```

Last thing to do, is to inject the `MongoConverter` into the template. It supplies the `MongoTemplate` with the mapping context. You will have to use an alternate constructor for that.

Replace:

```
<constructor-arg name="mongo" ref="mongo" />
<constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="${dbName}"/>
```

with:

```
<constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory"/>
<constructor-arg name="mongoConverter" ref="mongoConverter"/>
```

Comment: How can we achieve this configuration with annotations only?

Comment: Excellent answer.  And gawd I hate Spring.  @gba see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44995905/177920

Comment: @Madbreaks you linked to my answer :-)